# how to find all paths with a given node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph like this:

[here is th graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tpAu.png)

I want to find all paths with a given node. For example, If node "fcproc" is given, I expect to get a path("itest->bkqa->fcproc"); If node "itest" is given, I expect to get 2 paths("itest->bkqa->fcproc", "itest->xmonitor").

How to write the cypher?

Comment: Sounds like when you say "path" you mean a path from a root node to a leaf node? Or just to the node in question? If "bkqa" is given, are you expecting a path from "itest" to "bkqa", or all the way down to "fcproc"?

Comment: i mean path from root to leaf, and all pathes passed the given node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your target node has the label `Foo` and the `name` property value "fcproc", something like this should work:

```
MATCH p=(root)-[*0..]->(:Foo {name: "fcproc"})-[*0..]->(leaf)
WHERE NOT ()-->(root) AND NOT (leaf)-->()
RETURN p;
```

The variable-length relationship pattern `[*0..]` matches relationship lengths of 0 or more (where 0 means there is actually no relationship and the 2 "endpoints" are the same node). This allows the target node to be the same as the `root` or `leaf` node.